# Dynamically exclude some fields from select using EXCEPT

Tags: google-bigquery

We are looking for a way to dynamically exclude some columns from the result set, we tried using a case expression, but EXCEPT doesn't like it:

```
DECLARE hide_city  bool default true;
select * EXCEPT(case when hide_city then city end) from table
```

Do you know a way to achieve this? or some other ways?

Comment: I think you essentially looking for something like EXEC(query_text) which is not supported [hopefully yet]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know, you most likely expect something more sexy, but I feel this is the only option so far

```
DECLARE hide_city  bool DEFAULT TRUE;

IF hide_city THEN
  SELECT * EXCEPT(city) FROM table;
ELSE 
  SELECT * FROM table;
END IF;
```

> how to combine this with a CTE that goes before?

This can be something like below - so you "transform" your CTE into TEMP table

```
DECLARE hide_city  bool DEFAULT TRUE;

CREATE TEMP TABLE myTable AS 
WITH myCTE AS (
  SELECT ... UNION ALL
  SELECT ... UNION ALL
  ...
  SELECT ...
)
SELECT * FROM myCTE;

IF hide_city THEN
  SELECT * EXCEPT(city) FROM myTable;
ELSE 
  SELECT * FROM myTable;
END IF;
```

Obviously you don't need CTE at all and rather can do

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE myTable AS 
SELECT ... UNION ALL
SELECT ... UNION ALL
...
SELECT ...;
```

Comment: I put the Q up for brainstorming. Actually I have 5 to 10 columns any combination can be chosen.

Comment: as I said, i expected this - but conceptually (as of today) you still most likely will end up with above approach :o) obviously adjusted to whatever your real use case is

Comment: Do you know a way how to combine this with a CTE that goes before?

Comment: I have a 300 line common table expression. I tried to put between Declare and IF but it doesn't work out.

Comment: See update in answer based on how I understood it - even though there is a good chance that I might misunderstood use case and if so you might want to update your question with more details ...